# ShellExecuteEx + runas + file access permissions

Tags: c++, security, winapi, restriction, runas

My app started new process by ShellExecuteEx with "runas" verb in order to get administrator privilegies. New process creates some files in the user folder, but files can't be readed by built-in users. Only administrators can access those files. Same problem on XP and Vista.

I tried to read SetNamedSecurityInfo() docs but it's too complex for newbee. Can somebody tell how to just enable file read access for built-in users ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, don't use 'runas'.  It is nasty anyway.

Comment: @Hans, Nasty? It is one of 3 documented ways to show the uac dialog IIRC

Comment: Some code snippets would help us give you more effective advice.

Answer (score 1):

When a user creates a file, the file owner is set to that user by default. Therefore, when you run commands as the administrator that create files, those files are owned by the administrator, not you. You either need to find a smaller command to `runas` the administrator that doesn't create tons  of files, or you need to add another `runas` command that changes the ownership of those files back to your user.

I must confess I don't have experience in Windows programming, as I come from the Linux world, but I'm sure someone else can help you find the suitable commands if you post some code to help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The owner depends on a policy/registry setting when you are admin (“System objects: Default owner for objects created by members of the Administrators group” (nodefaultadminowner))